# Search bar isn't working and selection is gray (I want to be None)

Tags: swift, select, tableview, selection, uisearchbar

My search bar isn't working and I'm not sure why. I followed a tutorial online. There is a picture of my find friends view controller below and the code for the view controller.

Also even though in my storyboard selection is set to "None" it is gray on ios.

Not sure how to fix the selection part. Search bar fixed and solution is in comments below.

[image: Find Friends View Controller]

```
import UIKit

class FindFriendsViewController: UIViewController {

    var users = [User]()

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!

    var searchItem = [String]()
    var searching = false

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
        tableView.rowHeight = 71

        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self.view, action: #selector(UIView.endEditing(_:)))
        tap.cancelsTouchesInView = false
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        UserService.usersExcludingCurrentUser { [unowned self] (users) in
            self.users = users

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }
}

    extension FindFriendsViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        var usernamesArr = [String]()
        for user in users {
            usernamesArr.append(user.username)
        }

        if searching {
            return searchItem.count
        } else {
            return usernamesArr.count
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "FindFriendsCell") as! FindFriendsCell

        let user = users[indexPath.row]

        var usernamesArr = [String]()
        for user in users {
            usernamesArr.append(user.username)
        }

        if searching {
            cell.usernameLabel?.text = searchItem[indexPath.row]
        } else {
            cell.usernameLabel?.text = usernamesArr[indexPath.row]
            cell.delegate = self
            configure(cell: cell, atIndexPath: indexPath)
        }
        return cell
    }

    func configure(cell: FindFriendsCell, atIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let user = users[indexPath.row]

        cell.usernameLabel.text = user.username
        cell.followButton.isSelected = user.isFollowed
    }
}

    extension FindFriendsViewController: FindFriendsCellDelegate {
    func didTapFollowButton(_ followButton: UIButton, on cell: FindFriendsCell) {
        guard let indexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: cell) else { return }

        followButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        let followee = users[indexPath.row]

        FollowService.setIsFollowing(!followee.isFollowed, fromCurrentUserTo: followee) { (success) in
            defer {
                followButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
            }

            guard success else { return }

            followee.isFollowed = !followee.isFollowed
            self.tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)
        }
    }
}

    extension FindFriendsViewController: UISearchBarDelegate {
    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        var usernamesArr = [String]()
        for user in users {
            usernamesArr.append(user.username)
        }
        searchItem = usernamesArr.filter({$0.lowercased().prefix(searchText.count) == searchText.lowercased()})
        searching = true
        tableView.reloadData()
    }

    func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        searching = false
        searchBar.text = ""
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Comment: How exactly is it not working? When you type something, what happens? Do all the rows disappear? Or do all the user names stay as they were before the search?

Comment: When I search for something, the table view stays the same. Nothing changes.

Comment: Which tutorial? Is this your code or your friends code?

Comment: Have tried using the debugger? I think this should be the first step, try checking if the `searchItem` array is being populated, then if `searching` is changing from false to true.... etc etc. Your code for the searchBar seems fine BTW

Comment: Wait nvm!! Forgot to add "searchBar.delegate = self" in viewDidLoad yayyy works thanks guys